# How to bypass finish message while automating excel macro

Tags: python, excel, win32com

I am trying to automate an excel macro using the following code. However the close line did not execute. This might be caused by an auto-displayed finish message of the macro (which asks me to click ok) that prevents the code to move on.

Is there any way to bypass the finish message without editing the macro itself?

```
excel = win32.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.visible = 1
book = excel.Workbooks.Open(Filename = smething)
excel.Application.Run("Refresh")
book.close(False)
```

Comment: What is the content of the message ? It ask you if you want to quit without saving change ?

Comment: It is a message from the excel macro, something like "process finished".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Or:

```
Workbooks("WorkbookName").Close SaveChanges:=False
```

You would need to add it to the macro though.
Regards